# Как называется серия оборотов в фуэте? Или один оборот?

Tags: термины

Рабочий момент.

> Запомнился ярко один эпизод. Мы снимали балет. И с камерой
>   оказались именно там, куда должна была вбежать солистка, после
>   связки (УАУ! ОСТОРОЖНЕЕ! НЕТ ТАКОГО ТЕРМИНА! СКОРЕЕ ТУРЫ!) фуэте. И
>   пока она совершала свои вращения, мы слышали, как ей тихонько шептали
>   артисты на сцене: «Дыши, Наташенька, дыши!» Я помню, мы тогда
>   переглянулись и слёзы заблестели на наших глазах. После того дня мы в
>   тяжёлые моменты жизни друг другу подмигивали и повторяли: «Дыши,
>   Наташенька, дыши!»

Comment: В пределах 1 оборота (он может отличаться от 360 град) выделяют пируэты и туры. Сами обороты не группируют по количеству. Подробности есть в википедии на "пируэт" (статья "фуэте" менее информативна).

Comment: Саша, оформи ответом! Я извелась со статьёй "Фуэте".